# Change config file value in different page and proceed with execution

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to allow a user the option of using a feature or not in some software we have purchased.

It's imaging software and once the process is completed, a preview of the final image is created. I want to make this optional and have implemented the following code in the page that starts the job:

```
require_once("./config/client_config.inc");

<div><input type="checkbox" name="preview_option" value="make_preview">Generate preview?</div>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['preview_option'])) {

$useThumbnails = true;

} else {

$useThumbnails = false;

}
```

The file client_config.inc holds the option for "useThumbnails"
If the user checks the box, I wanted it to set the value to true, otherwise set it to false. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you missing something? What is not working? What have you tried to fix it? From what you have shared you're missing form tags, and you're setting `$useThumbnails` AFTER you call client_config.inc which might or might not be a problem... can't tell because you didn't include the relevant code from client_config.

Comment: the code from client_config.php is $use_Thumbnails = true;

Comment: That makes no sense to me...